# Mixed type in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm struggling to create a bibliography with mixed type.

I found on some websites ([like this](https://bu.univ-amu.libguides.com/c.php?g=511707&p=3496584) it's in French, sorry) that it's possible to do:

```
\printbibliography[type=book,article]
```

but it's generating an error.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: for info, in my .bib file I don't use the "key" argument, I just use the @book, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `type` filter option only accepts one value and not multiple values connected with a comma. (In the code example from the question `type=book,article` would be parsed as two distinct options. One option `type=book,` which filters books, and another option called `article`, which doesn't exist and therefore throws an error. But even something like `type={book,article},` which would work around this issue will not work as intended.)

Multiple higher-level filter options to `\printbibliography` (`type`, `keyword`, `category` and their `not...` versions) are always concatenated with a logical *and*.

So it is not possible to write something like

```
\printbibliography[type=article, type=book]
```

to filter entries that are `@article`s *or* `@book`s.

## Filters

For more complex filter rules one usually uses *filters* defined by `\defbibfilter`. That allows us to put together several of the higher-level checks with the logical connectives *not*, *or* and *and*.

A filter for `@book` or `@article` would be defined as follows

```
\defbibfilter{bookorarticle}{%
  \type{book} \or \type{article}
}
```

and used as

```
\printbibliography[filter=bookorarticle, title={Books and Articles}]
```

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibfilter{bookorarticle}{%
  \type{book} \or \type{article}
}

\defbibfilter{notbookorarticle}{%
  \not \( \type{book} \or \type{article} \)
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[filter=bookorarticle, title={Books and Articles}]
\printbibliography[filter=notbookorarticle, title={The Rest}]
\end{document}
```

## Checks

For even more complex filters which can execute arbitrary code one would define a *check* with `\defbibcheck`, but this would be overkill here. Checks don't have the syntactic sugar of filters and so the code may look a bit more daunting at first. The same tests as above would be coded as

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{bookorarticle}{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
       {}
       {\skipentry}}}

\defbibcheck{notbookorarticle}{%
  \ifentrytype{book}
    {\skipentry}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
       {\skipentry}
       {}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[check=bookorarticle, title={Books and Articles}]
\printbibliography[check=notbookorarticle, title={The Rest}]
\end{document}
```

## Multiple `nottype`s

Finally, you could simply use several `nottype`s (which are joined with an *and*) to kick out all types except for `@book` and `@article`. Of course this requires you to know all possible other entry types or at least all entry types you used.

In the example I used so far that was very simple since the only other type was `@thesis`, but in general things would get quite a bit longer

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\printbibliography[nottype=thesis, nottype=inbook,
                   nottype=incollection, nottype=online,
                   nottype=misc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer @moewe !

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.

I used `nottype=misc, nottype=...`

`nottype` can be used multiple times as opposed to `type`, apparently...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you are pleased with this solution, you can also accept the answer, even if you wrote it yourself (or you could wait for someone else to come up with a better one).

Comment: You could wait also for upvotes  if you provide [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with an image of the output. As is, your solution could be indecipherable  or hardly verifiable for the novice.